# Для слайдера сделать возможность выбирать диапазон кликом

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Есть такой вот слайдер http://danielcrisp.github.io/angular-rangeslider/demo

Всё хорошо работает,но в нем нельзя выбирать диапазон кликнув по полоске,только перетаскиванием двух ползунков,никак не могу разобраться как сделать по клику.

Вот js этого слайдера https://github.com/danielcrisp/angular-rangeslider/blob/master/angular.rangeSlider.js

Нашел только такой кусок кода в котором идет выполнение событий при клике на сами ползунки

```
                      function handleMove(index) {

                        var $handle = handles[index];

                        // on mousedown / touchstart
                        $handle.bind(onEvent + 'X', function(event) {

                            var handleDownClass = (index === 0 ? 'ngrs-handle-min' : 'ngrs-handle-max') + '-down',
                                //unbind = $handle.add($document).add('body'),
                                modelValue = (index === 0 ? modelMin() : modelMax()) - scope.min,
                                originalPosition = (modelValue / range) * 100,
                                originalClick = client(event),
                                previousClick = originalClick,
                                previousProposal = false;
.....
```

Comment: Это вам надо обращаться к автору слайда,

Comment: Автор давно забросил проект и не отвечает,писал ему на гит

Comment: В таком случае, может поискать другой, более адекватный слайдер? А то мне кажется, менять код существующего задача не на 5 минут.

Comment: да я пробовал другой применить,просто проект привязан жестко на этом слайдере

Comment: Ну раз жестко привязан, значит вам нужен программист, который бы смог поменять код существующего слайдера. Могу взяться, не бесплатно.

Comment: А вы не хотите помочь проекту?Автора даже спрашивали об этом)
https://github.com/danielcrisp/angular-rangeslider/issues/41

Comment: Нет, у меня нет желания заниматься чьей-то работой бесплатно. Извините, но я не альтруист :-)